# How can I fill an input text with a session variable using Crispy forms?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I need to auto complete a field with a session variable if exists, or leave it in blank if not.

But I have no idea how to make it in Django using Crispy forms.

This is the view:

```
def addclient(request):
    title = "Zona Clientes"
    form = NewClientForm(request.POST or None)

    if 'dni_cuit' in request.session:
        dni_cuit = request.session.get('dni_cuit')
        print("ESTÁ REGISTRADA LA SESSION DNI_CUIT"+dni_cuit)
        context = {
               "title": title,
               "form": form,
               "dni_cuit": dni_cuit
              }
    else:
        context = {
               "title": title,
               "form": form,
              }

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        del request.session['dni_cuit']

        # Las 2 lineas anteriores pueden obviarse si solo queremos guardar
        # los datos sin hacer nada con ellos con la siguiente linea
        # form.save()

        context = {
                   "title": "Cliente Añadido - Gracias",
        }

    return render(request, "clients/addclient.html", context)
```

This is the form:

```
# Formulario crear cliente
class NewClientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['dni_cuit',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'phone',
                  'email',
                  'address',
                  ]

    def clean_dni_cuit(self):
        dni_cuit = self.cleaned_data.get('dni_cuit')
        return dni_cuit

    def clean_first_name(self):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        return first_name

    def clean_last_name(self):
        last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        return last_name

    def clean_phone(self):
        phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        return phone

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        return email

    def clean_address(self):
        address = self.cleaned_data.get('address')
        return address
```

Can anyone told me how to put in the input for `dni_cuit` the Value stored on `dni_cuit` if is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use form initial values

> Use initial to declare the initial value of form fields at runtime.
>   For example, you might want to fill in a username field with the
>   username of the current session.
>
> To accomplish this, use the initial argument to a Form. This argument,
>   if given, should be a dictionary mapping field names to initial
>   values. Only include the fields for which you’re specifying an initial
>   value; it’s not necessary to include every field in your form.

So in your case you check the session and decide if it's needed or not.

```
if 'dni_cuit' in request.session:
    form = NewClientForm(request.POST or None, initial={'dni_cuit': request.session['dni_cuit']})
else:
    form = NewClientForm(request.POST or None)
```

---

Read more about it in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)